# Typing my own ip address redirects to router settings

Tags: webserver, xampp

So basically I am just trying to turn my PC into a webserver. I found [this tutorial](http://tech-blog10.blogspot.in/2011/08/creating-your-own-web-server.html).

Followed each and every step he mentioned.

My results (Browser-Firefox):

- localhost -> it works
- 127.0.0.1 -> it works
- But when I type my own public ip address 59.182.xx.xx it redirects me
  to my adsl modem settings page

What am I missing here? It should show xampp default page right?

Comment: "public ip address 59.182.xx.xx it **redirects me to my adsl modem settings page**" you should definitely avoid that!

Comment: Please ask that in a comment under that article. We can not support that article, but the author of that article most certainly can.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some article written by somebody but not on the Stackoverflow website.

Comment: @hakre — It's about configuring a web server, and there is sufficient description of the problem to understand it without having to look at the learning material the OP used.

Comment: @Quentin: Sounds contradictory to your answer which is about network configuration (routing), not webserver configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your connection to the Internet is provided by NAT. This means your computer is not directly connected to the Internet and it doesn't have an IP address on the Internet.

Your computer only has a LAN (and a loopback) IP address. The router has a LAN and an Internet IP address and is responsible for passing traffic between them.

If you want to expose a service on your computer to the Internet then you either need to give it its own Internet facing IP address (this isn't usually possible on a residential Internet account and has a number of security implications as you will expose all the services you run to the Internet) or configure your router to perform port forwarding (so a request to the HTTP server port on the router gets forwarded (by the router) to the computer inside the LAN).

Comment: At first everything went above the head, but now I am gonna give it a shot!

Answer (score 2):

The port 80 is used by the router/modem, you should init the server in another port and unlock it at firewall and forward the port in the modem/router.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access your router and say that everything that comes on port 80 goes to the ip of your machine running Apache server.